# Placebo test for triple DiD regression

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am currently trying to run a regression working out the change in the mental well-being of ethnic individuals in a set of countries after a migration policy was imposed. I have two waves of data, one before the policy and one after the policy. Essentially the control group are non-ethnic individuals in the countries while the treatment group are the ethnic individuals in the country. The model is:

[image: 〖Mental Wellbeing〗_cit=δ_0+δ_1 Country+δ_2 〖Ethnic〗_ic+δ_3 〖PostPolicy〗_t+δ_4 (Country  〖PostPolicy〗_t )+ δ_5 (Country  〖Ethnic〗_ic ) δ_6 (〖Ethnic〗_ic  〖PostPolicy〗_t  Country)+ω_ict+ε_ict]

Where, Country - is the name of the country analysed Ethnic - is a dummy variable for whether the individual is an ethnic =1 or non-ethnic=0 Post policy - Is for the individuals interviewed in the second period, after the policy had been placed. 1 if in second wave and 0 otherwise.

Given this the coefficient of interest is δ_6 as it shows the difference in the well-being of ethnic and non-ethnic individuals after the policy had been imposed. It captures the difference-in-difference indifference.

For this I know I don't need to rely on the parallel trend assumption as I only have two time periods. However, I could then run a placebo test where I can change the pre-treatment year. However, I am confused about how I would go about this. I have two waves, one wave for before the policy which includes the years 2014 and 2015. Then the second wave is for after the policy which includes the years 2018 and 2019. I created these waves myself based on the fact the individuals where interviewed in either of the 2 years within the two waves. So how would I then run a placebo test?

Comment: Do you observe individuals in any waves before 2014?

Comment: There is an additional dataset for different waves but that is for the year  2002

Comment: I was wondering if there is any other type of robustness check to kind of run for my model